# Trying to Annotate a MapView and Load a second View Controller Simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview, segue

Inside my Primary View Controller I have a MKMapView and TableView. The tableview is using AlamoFire to call an API of user information to populate its cells.

**What I would like to happen:**
When you select a cell, a second container view, with more detailed user information, will segue into the portion of the screen where the tableview was. At the same time, the Map View will annotate with that user's location.

**The problem:**
When the cell is selected, the second container view slides onto the screen (good), the Map Annotates (good), but then the info container view disappears again (bad). With a second tap of the originally selected cell, the info container view slides back onto the screen to stay. I need to get rid of this double tap.

It appears that the Map Annotation is negating this process for some reason. When I comment out the map annotation, the VC transition works fine... with one tap.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Here is the offending code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.localTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.populateInfoContainerView(indexPath.row)

        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.users[indexPath.row], animated: true)

        if(self.userInfoContainerView.frame.origin.x == UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width){
            self.showInfoView(true)

        } else {
            self.hideInfoView(true)
        }
    })

}

func showInfoView(animated: Bool){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: ({
        self.userInfoContainerView.frame.origin.x = 0
        self.localTableView.frame.origin.x = -UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    }), completion: { finished in
        //animation complete
    })
    self.infoVisible = true
}

func hideInfoView(animated: Bool){
    let xPos = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

    if(animated == true){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: ({
            self.userInfoContainerView.frame.origin.x = xPos
            self.localTableView.frame.origin.x = 0
        }), completion: { finished in
            //animation complete
        })
    } else {
        self.userInfoContainerView.frame.origin.x = xPos
    }
    self.infoVisible = false
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found an answer. I'm not sure why this works and the above version does not, but I'll show you what I did different.

I am now animating the constraints of the TableView and the InfoView.

First, I ctrl+click+drag the constraint from my main.storyboard into my code and created an IBOutlet to animate. I also added a `let screenWidth` as the constant that I would move them by.

```
@IBOutlet weak var infoViewLeadingEdge: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewXCenter: NSLayoutConstraint!
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
```

Then I replaced the code above in `showInfo()`:

```
self.userInfoContainerView.frame.origin.x = 0
self.localTableView.frame.origin.x = -UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
```

with this new code:

```
self.infoViewLeadingEdge.constant -= self.screenWidth
self.tableViewXCenter.constant += self.screenWidth
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

In my `hideInfo()` above, I replaced this:

```
self.userInfoContainerView.frame.origin.x = xPos
self.localTableView.frame.origin.x = 0
```

with this new code:

```
self.infoViewLeadingEdge.constant += self.screenWidth
self.tableViewXCenter.constant -= self.screenWidth
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Don't forget the `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`. If you don't use that code, the animations won't work. Also, the += and -= on the tableViewXCenter seem opposite of what I want the table to do, however, this is the way I needed to put them in order to get the table to move the direction I wanted. It did seem counterintuitive though.

And that's it. I hope this will be helpful to someone.